# How can I pass the ip address of a docker container as an environment variable to other docker containers in the same bridge network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-machine

I have three micro-services, A, B, and C. They all talk with each other. I am using docker-compose to build their containers and connect them using bridge-network. In this network however, the containers must know the internal IP addresses of each other. How can they know that without manually setting them after starting the containers? Can this somehow be set by docker-compose automatically?

Edit:
I tried using the service name as the DNS name in the microservices, (here Django server). However I am getting the following error. `user_interaction` is the service name here.

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'user_interaction:8000'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
Bad Request: /interactions/top_contents
[08/Jan/2022 15:04:13] "GET /interactions/top_contents HTTP/1.1" 400 60583
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'user_interaction:8000'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
Bad Request: /interactions/top_contents
[08/Jan/2022 15:04:15] "GET /interactions/top_contents HTTP/1.1" 400 60583
```

Comment: Why do you need the IP? Why is the DNS name (i.e. the container name) not sufficient?

Comment: Seems it is application issue, not docker.

Comment: Have you tried to prefix the hostname with `http`?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I have tried, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: What docker image are you using that causes this error?

Comment: All three services are django servers using python:3.9.9-alpine3.14 image. And I am using python requests library to make the requests from one container to another.

Comment: Okay it is an application error as ping to other containers with their DNS was successful.